# Fetching Current Location with Permission not working

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am using 
geolocator: '^3.0.1'
permission_handler: '^3.0.0'

Now I want to fetch the current location of the user and show it on the map as the user opens the Map.

So my Code is :

```
Future<void> requestPermission() async {
    PermissionHandler()
        .checkPermissionStatus(PermissionGroup.location)
        .then((PermissionStatus permissionStatus) async {
      print("Checking Permission " + permissionStatus.toString());
      if (permissionStatus == PermissionStatus.granted) {
        _getCurrentLocation();
      } else {
        print("Asking Permission " + permissionStatus.toString());

        final List<PermissionGroup> permissions = <PermissionGroup>[
          PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse
        ];
        final Map<PermissionGroup, PermissionStatus> permissionRequestResult =
            await PermissionHandler().requestPermissions(permissions);

        if (PermissionStatus.granted ==
            permissionRequestResult[PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse]) {
          print("Permission Granted " + permissionStatus.toString());

          _getCurrentLocation();
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

and permissions are defined in the manifest for android and info.list for IOS.

Now the issue is when I run this function and when it calls `requestPermission` function, it shows the popup asking for the permission and

when I `allow the permission` app crashes with an error :

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions: ... java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reply already submitted`

and also the result of permission is `Permission.disabled` though I allowed the permission in application settings and in permission it shows that location is permission is allowed. but I tried opening app several times it shows Permission.disabled.

and even if I `deny` the app crashes with the same error.

So what I have concluded is :

If I `allow` or `deny`  it crashes because it is requesting multiple times and even if I allow the result is Permission.disabled.

Link for the video: https://youtu.be/A1DKkw6u4HI

Can anyone help me solving this issue?

`Or please tell me how to take the current location map easily`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> please tell me how to take the current location map easily

If you just need to fetch current location easily and you just need location permission then :

you can use `location` plugin with flutter :

In your `pubspec.yml` :   `location : ^2.3.0`

Then for fetching Current location :

**Import location Package**

```
 import 'package:location/location.dart' as locationPackage;
```

**Add this to your State**

```
 locationPackage.Location _locationService = new locationPackage.Location();
     bool _permission = false;
```

**Call this function in initState or whenever you need current Location**

```
fetchCurrentLocation() async {
    await _locationService.changeSettings(
        accuracy: locationPackage.LocationAccuracy.HIGH, interval: 1000);

    locationPackage.LocationData location;
    // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
    try {
      bool serviceStatus = await _locationService.serviceEnabled();
      print("Service status: $serviceStatus");
      if (serviceStatus) {
        _permission = await _locationService.requestPermission();
        print("Permission: $_permission");
        if (_permission) {
          location = await _locationService.getLocation();

          print("Location: ${location.latitude}");
        }
      } else {
        bool serviceStatusResult = await _locationService.requestService();
        print("Service status activated after request: $serviceStatusResult");
        if (serviceStatusResult) {
          fetchCurrentLocation();
        }
      }
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print(e);
      if (e.code == 'PERMISSION_DENIED') {
        //error = e.message;
      } else if (e.code == 'SERVICE_STATUS_ERROR') {
        //error = e.message;
      }
      location = null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I will check this oode and revert you.

Comment: @CodeGeek Have you checked? Does it work?